# T-SQL Union with Dissimilar Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with the following data:

```
[Animals].[Males]
DataID                               HerdNumber HerdID  NaabCode
e46fff54-a784-46ed-9a7f-4c81e649e6a0 4          'GOLDA' '7JE1067'
fee3e66b-7248-44dd-8670-791a6daa5d49 1          '35'    NULL

[Animals].[Females]
DataID                               HerdNumber HerdID   BangsNumber
987110c6-c938-43a7-a5db-194ce2162a20 1          '9'      'NB3829483909488'
1fc83693-9b8a-4054-9d79-fbd66ee99091 2          'NATTIE' 'ID2314843985499'
```

I want to merge these tables into a view that looks like this:

```
DataID                               HerdNumber HerdID   NaabCode  BangsNumber
e46fff54-a784-46ed-9a7f-4c81e649e6a0 4          'GOLDA'  '7JE1067' NULL
fee3e66b-7248-44dd-8670-791a6daa5d49 1          '35'     NULL      NULL
987110c6-c938-43a7-a5db-194ce2162a20 1          '9'      NULL      'NB3829483909488'
1fc83693-9b8a-4054-9d79-fbd66ee99091 2          'NATTIE' NULL      'ID2314843985499'`
```

When I used the `UNION` keyword, SQL Server produced a view that merged the `NaabCode` and `BangsNumber` into one column. A book that I have on regular SQL suggested `UNION CORRESPONDING` syntax like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Animals].[Males]
UNION CORRESPONDING (DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID)
SELECT *
FROM [Animals].[Females]`
```

But when I type this SQL Server says "Incorrect syntax near 'CORRESPONDING'."

Can anyone tell me how to achieve my desired result and/or how to use `UNION CORRESPONDING` in T-SQL?

Comment: UNION CORRESPONDING is not supported in SQL Server. Enumerate the column names in the SELECT clause and don't use ´SELECT *´

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do:

```
SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, NaabCode, NULL as BangsNumber
FROM [Animals].[Males]
UNION ALL
SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, NULL as NaabCode, BangsNumber
FROM [Animals].[Females]
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94929/2)**

I don't remember that SQL Server supports the `corresponding` syntax, but I might be wrong.
Anyway, this query will select `null` for the `BangsNumber` column for the males, and for the `NaabCode` column for the females, while selecting everything else correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the `union` explicitly listing the columns:

```
select DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, NaabCode, NULL as BangsNumber
from Animals.Males
union all
select DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, NULL, BangsNumber
from Animals.Females;
```

Note:  you should use `union all` instead of `union` (assuming that no single animal is both male and female).  `union` incurs a performance overhead to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, NaabCode, '' asBangsNumber
  FROM [Animals].[Males] 
UNION ALL
 SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID, '' as NaabCode, BangsNumber
  FROM [Animals].[Females]
```

Comment: `null` is better than `''`.  There could be an issue with data types, also `null` implies there is no data, while `''` implies there is, it is just blank.

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality post queue. You should attach an explanation as to why / how this fixes OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to state the columns in each select

```
SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID
FROM [Animals].[Males]
UNION 
SELECT DataID, HerdNumber, HerdID
FROM [Animals].[Females]
```